# Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wp-login.php on this server

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I have one problem with all my WordPress's sites. I can access in all and navigate in the posts, pages and other. But when I go to `wp-login.php` I view the form and put user and password.

And when I clicking access goes here:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /blog/wp-login.php on this server.

I have permissions in folder `755` and files `644`, and I check all if i can, any help?

Thanks

Comment: There's a [brute force attack on WordPress websites](http://blog.sucuri.net/2013/04/protecting-against-wordpress-brute-force-attacks.html) right now. Your host probably blacklisted your IP to mitigate this attack. Try to contact them for further help.

Answer (score 56):

The solution is to add this to the beginning of your .htaccess

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Files>
```

It's because many hosts were under attack, using the wordpress from their clients.

Comment: This can be used to access any file you're having trouble with. For example, replace wp-login with install if you're getting the message when trying to complete a wordpress installation.

Comment: this worked.  but I was also able to tighten it down a bit by changing `Allow from all` to `Allow from <my-machine's-ip>`.  You can be more open, allowing a range of IPs.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow

Comment: This answer should be on the top.

Comment: can someone explain this please, i read the docs and i gather this means all requests will be denied unless they match an allow, so basically all are allowed. so what is the point of this as opposed to not having it at all or just having 'allow from all'?

Comment: I had this same issue and I added this to my .htaccess within my WP install folder and was able to fix the issue.  Refreshed my login page and was able to log in just like normal.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, and after temporarily deleting all my .htaccess files, then trying to modify them as suggested, and making sure all my files and folder permissions were set to `777`, I still couldn't get it to work. I don't know why I couldn't access the file, but I was able to create a new file and access it no problem. So what I did was create a new file in `/wp-admin/` called `temp.php` and pasted all the code from `install.php` into it. This allowed me to access the file. The only other thing I had to do was edit the code so that the form submitted to temp.php instead of install.php. After that, I could finish the install and everything worked.

`<form id="setup" method="post" action="temp.php?step=2">`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the following lines are not in your wp.config

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
```

I got locked out after deactivating iThemes security plugin

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you are using some simple login info like this:
username: 'admin' and
pass: 'admin', the hosting is seeing you as a potential Brute Force Attack through WP login file, and blocks you IP address or that particularly file.

**I had that issue with ixwebhosting and just got that info from their support guy.** They must unban your IP in this situation. And you must change your WP admin login info to something more secure.

That solved my problem.

Comment: Please, explain down votes. I got this from my hosting provider, and it is specific issue for them as I mentioned. It did solve my problem. Modifying .htaccess didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, which was fixed by adding:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

... in the `apps/[app-name]/conf/httpd-app.conf` file. This is because, in my case, an `.htaccess` file wants to use rewrite rules, that are not allowed with FollowSymLinks AND SymLinksIfOwnerMatch turned off.

If your conf file already has a line with `Options ...`, you can just add `FollowSymLinks` to the list of options. You could end up with something like this:

```
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

The instructions says that you add a separate .htaccess containing the lines above to the wp-admin folder - and leave the main .htaccess, in the root, alone.

if that don't help , you can try this:

copy the .htaccess file as is from the wp-admin and placed it in the root folder and bingo! 
It should work ! if you face new error after this let us know.

for reference you can look here as well:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-blogwp-loginphp-on-this-server

Check using this:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please summarise the contents of that page here. If the link ever dies this answer will become useless.

Comment: Hello devilcrab thanks for your answered, i checking this link before posting but i dont have good look. Not running =S

Any help?

Comment: @user2274068  what is the error now ? can you show screenshot or give me link to error ?  and check the above method that i updated.

Comment: The link: http://discoverit.cat/blog/wp-login.php

(You can try with any user pass and can see the error)

Hi, so I'm try to put one .htaccess with this content:

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

Into wp-admin/

And the default .htacces in the root:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

And then this not working =S

Comment: Try this:  

<IfModule mod_security.c>   
SecFilterEngine Off  
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

Comment: Yes im checking this <IfModule mod_security.c> SecFilterEngine Off SecFilterScanPOST Off </IfModule> i said in the last comment but not work

Comment: can you update your main post with your .htaccess file code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iThemes Security plugin (former Better WP security) please refer to the answer provided by Mikeys4u.

Also, there is a similar thread related to this plugin on the WordPress support: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-reset-ithemes-security-plugin-to-fix-issues

Make sure you backup your database before trying any of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Change .htaccess file code by this code :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Why? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your apache .conf files are correct -- then double check your .htaccess files. In this case, my .htaccess were incorrect! I removed some weird stuff no longer needed and it worked. Tada.

Answer (score 0):

I got recently this error and i used the solution which is proposed by @SirPaul. But the error was existing on the other configuration pages of the WordPress like `update-core.php` .

The solution that i have found, **which resolved all the permission problems**, was to deactivate `iThemes Security plugin` and update it and reactivate it.