# Forbidden when accessing the wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Here is the message which i get when Accessing the Wordpress Admin panel 
after enter the user name and Passowrd:
**Forbidden**
i've tried every thing to get out of it like,
changing the .htaccess file and adding this piece of code

```
<Files wp-login.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
Allow from all
</Files>
```

this one can'nt solve my problem too
[Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wp-login.php on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969527/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-wp-login-php-on-this-server)

also tried this one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirect_to=http
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php http://example.com/wp-login.php? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

what else should i missing not able to login for the previous two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem you are facing.  You must have change the network from which you are accessing the admin panel. This is because nowadays, the hosting providers blocks the IP address from which the WordPress sites admin panels are accessed frequently. The same thing happens here too. As such, change the network access and try again.  This should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: must give you credit for suggestion, in office switch to other network and works. Thumbs uppp buddy