# Wordpress reauth=1 Loop

Tags: wordpress

I do have a wordpress blog which is stored locally on my servers. Recently I upgraded the WordPress core from 3.6 to 4.0. It wasn't updated for a long time. Now everything works fine except logins. When I try to login as an admin, it redirects me to the login page.

Here is what I did;

I cleared my browser's cache and cookies.

I disabled all the plugins.

I deactivated the current theme

I edited the site_url option in WP_OPTIONS table,

but non of these worked for me. The url is devsvr.tempora.com:8000/blog

Comment: Have you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, this can be solved by using this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16005976/1131990

At the beginning of .htaccess, add:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably happens three things

1. Transfer files can interrupted and files are not copied and rewrite completely. (Helps manually download and rewrite)
2. Sometimes needs change "salt" keys in wp-config.php file.
3. And (probably) your current theme or active plugins not working correctly with new version. More info you can see in Error Log or try to deactivate plugins (for short time) via rename Plugin folder.

It's not all issues but most frequently.

Comment: I already tried all of them, but still the looping problem continues.

Comment: Hi @BurakErgenc! What about BOM signature (common in wp-config.php or functions.php theme files) or space (empty line) before `<?php` or after `?>` in this files?

Comment: This did not work also. I'm using WordPress with Interspire Shopping Cart integration. If I delete the shopping card embedding the site just works fine.

Comment: Changing salt keys in wp-config.php file help use fix this issue today. Before that tried most of the other suggestions here on Stackoverflow, but without any result